# Compare files within folders between local computer and remote server

Tags: unix, diff, remote-server, file-comparison

I have one folder on my computer and one folder on a remote server, I transferred a large number of files but for some reason I have now 2 more files in my own folder than on the server so I would like to check which ones these are instead of going through them all manually. 
I looked for directory comparison and I found the command `diff` to display differences, but I tried it for my different two folders and it couldn't find the directory on the remote server. This is what I tried:

`diff /Volumes/TC1-SIMDATA/Parallel/ModelWSSim/ fraukje@localhost:parallel/ModelWSSim/`

Could anyone hint me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `diff` command works only with file system accessible files and folders (i.e. mounted folders generally speaking).

If you can mount the folders, you'll be able to compare them with `diff`, else you need to invest some time to find a good diff merge tool with FTP or SFTP or whatever access protocol that you need.